# RecyclerView Item does not wrap height of ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-recyclerview

So I have this activity, which looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jonas.trainingslog1.WorkoutDataActivity">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                ...
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, the activity has an RecyclerView which items look like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lst"/>
```

The Height of the `ListView` in the `RecyclerView` Item should only be as tall as its content, so I set it to `wrap_content`. The problem is, this only works as long as I have set the height of the `RecyclerView` Item Layout to `match_parent`, as soon as I change it to `wrap_content` the ListView shows only one item. How ever I cant leave the height of the `RecyclerView` Item as `match_parent` because then every item of the `RecyclerView` has a lot of unused space.

Anyone hows how to fix this problem? I dont understand this behavior of the xml files. I would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to you listview...set the height of the listview dynamically

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(final ListView listView) {
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
        int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));


            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.d("listItemHeight " + listItem.getMeasuredHeight(), "********");
        }

        Log.d("totalHeight " + totalHeight, "********");

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1)));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }
});
}
```

add this to your recyclerview adapter

Comment: Not all heros wear capes! Thank you this works great.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a vertical linear layout where you put all your content of the page. Then set the height of the views (including the recyclerview) to 0dp and add a layout weight.